# How to permanently stop "A new iPhone software version..." notifications

Tags: ios, jailbreak

I jailbreak my phone and therefore can't always update to the newest iOS version as soon as it is released.

How do I permanently remove all notifications about iOS updates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As referenced in this forum](https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/3ppuc1/question_cant_get_rid_of_system_update/), you can use Mikoto from cydia.angelxwind.net to disable iOS updates, which should stop giving you update notifications.